# How implement dynamic dependent select dropdown with node js, mongoDB and vue js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, express

I want to implement the dynamic dependent dropdown list with node js, mongoDB and Vue js and I could not figure out where to start (sorry I'm new to this topic), here is my scenario below:

I have 2 dropdown boxes **country** and **state**, I want **state** to change every time accordingly to the selected **country** [image]

so do you have any idea on how to implement this one?
Any idea would be appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take small steps.

1 - First you need to plan your basic API, I'd not bother at all with the backend at the beggining just start with a simple Vue app this is all you need.

2 - [Countries and Cities JSON repository](https://github.com/russ666/all-countries-and-cities-json) download this, this will be the shape of your API, and import that JSON object directly to your Vuejs app.

Now this is some basic code to give you an idea, you can handle the implementation.

```js
import countries from './countries.json'

const countryNames = Object.keys(countries)

const citiesOfGermany = countries.Germany
```

3 - Once you have finished the basic frontend, I'd start with Nodejs, setup a basic endpoint and serve this exact JSON. ie: `GET /countries`

4 - Now make the request from your Vuejs APP to this endpoint.

5 - Finally migrate this JSON file to MongoDB, and replace the json file in your nodejs server with MongoDB implementation.

Good luck!

Comment: Really appreciate your time of explaining this, okay let's me start with the simple frontend stuff as you mentioned above and I will get back to you once I finish the set up frontend

Comment: Hi, can you tell me the backend part on how to implement its schema design as well as sample route API?

Comment: `const countries = require('./countries.json')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.json())

app.get('/countries', (req, res) => res.json(countries))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on ${port}!`))`

But actually, read the [Express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html), don't  blindly copy paste. There's plenty of information out there about this, google and you'll find everything.

Comment: I know that one, can you tell more about the mongoDB schema design between country and state because it might connected with each other. Thanks

Comment: I don't remember the last time I used MongoDB, read the [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) ^^. There is all you need, tip: the schema it's already defined in the JSON file if you look at it, you just have to translate that to a Mongoose Schema.